# How does the JetBrains IdeaVIM plugin indicate Insertion and Normal mode?

Tags: intellij-idea, vi, jetbrains-ide, goland, ideavim

In ordinary vim, the lower left shows NORMAL and INSERT as I switch between those two modes.

How do I see the mode in [IdeaVIM](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim)?

(I am using  GoLand but it is the same in IntelliJ, PyCharm, etc.)

I tried switching back and forth between Normal and Insert mode, but cannot find any indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `set showmode` to your `~/.ideavimrc`.

More options can be found here: https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/wiki/%22set%22-commands

Answer (score 1):

I have stiil problems to display mode in idea vim and I add to ideavimrc

```
set showmode
set ideastatusicon=enabled
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).